# Can't do cf ic login with http proxy

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix container service and am unable to do cf ic login from behind a firewall, even though I have configured proxies.

When I do

```
cf ic -v login
```

I get the error message:

> Authenticating with the IBM Containers registry host
>   registry.ng.bluemix.net... FAILED The attempt to authenticate with the
>   IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net was unsuccessful.
>   ****Warning: '-e' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage. Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/users/: dial tcp
>   198.23.117.106:443: i/o timeout

To test that my proxy is configured, I do this:

> wget https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/users/
>
> --2016-10-25 11:25:23--  https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/users/ Resolving proxy-chain.intel.com (proxy-chain.intel.com)... 10.19.8.225
>   Connecting to proxy-chain.intel.com
>   (proxy-chain.intel.com)|10.19.8.225|:912... connected. Proxy request
>   sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2016-10-25 11:25:24 ERROR
>   404: Not Found.

If I disconnect VPN so I no longer have a firewall and need a proxy, and unset my proxies, it works.

These are the proxies I have set:

> printenv | grep -i proxy
>
> http_proxy=http://proxy-chain.intel.com:911
>
> ftp_proxy=http://proxy-chain.intel.com:911
>
> socks_proxy=http://proxy-chain.intel.com:1080
>
> https_proxy=http://proxy-chain.intel.com:912
>
> no_proxy=intel.com,.intel.com,10.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16,localhost,127.0.0.0/8,134.134.0.0/16
>   >

More experiments:

When I set the proxy to something bogus, it fails immediately:

```
> export https_proxy=http://foobarsfsdf.com
> cf ic login
FAILED
auth request failed: Error performing request: Post https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token: http: error connecting to proxy http://foobarsfsdf.com: dial tcp: lookup foobarsfsdf.com on 10.0.2.3:53: no such host
>
```

When I set the proxy correctly, it fails later:

```
> cf ic login
Deleting old configuration file...
Retrieving client certificates for IBM Containers...
Storing client certificates in /home/rscohn1/.ice/certs/...

Storing client certificates in /home/rscohn1/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/80cc2e8c-4df0-4700-bd04-77f2e8777f80...

OK
The client certificates were retrieved.

Checking local Docker configuration...
OK

Authenticating with the IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net...
FAILED
The attempt to authenticate with the IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net was unsuccessful.
****Warning: '-e' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/users/: dial tcp 198.23.117.106:443: i/o timeout


When you are not connected to the IBM Containers registry host, you can run only a limited number of IBM Containers commands. Check the spelling of the host URL and try again. If the host URL is correct, open a new command line or terminal window before retrying.
```

It looks like some parts of the ic plugin uses proxies, and some parts do not.

Comment: can you try to use the ip address on the https_proxy env variable and see if that works?

Comment: using the ip address does not help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proxy on to your Docker daemon configuration. Also note that as Alex says, you should make sure to configure a HTTPS proxy.

See here for some information on how to do that with Systemd on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04+): https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy

For older Linux distributions, such as Ubuntu versions before 16.04, Docker uses Upstart. You'll find the Upstart configuration file at `/etc/default/docker`, with a sample of how to set the proxy up in comments inside that file.

If you're using the Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows apps, you'll find the proxy configuration options in **Preferences** -> **Advanced**.

Make sure to restart Docker after changing the configuration, so that your changes take effect. On Linux: `sudo service docker restart`. On Mac or Windows, right-click the Docker icon and click **restart**.

Comment: I can use docker with the proxy, so I know my docker daemon is configured for the proxy. The problem is trying to log in to the Bluemix container service with the 'cf ic login' command. It looks like it is using my proxy for some things but not all remote requests.